# Dynamically add text in an image on Xaml/Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, image-formats

I have a XAML ListBox where I am implementing an Image beside that a block of text is there. I want to display a count text in that image. For example for the first block in the image I want to display 1, for the 2nd block I want to display 2. This goes on. Below is the snippet. Can anybody please help me how can I write the count numbers in the image?

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
 <Image Source="/Assets/Images/pin.png"></Image>
  </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="locationID" Visibility="Collapsed" ></TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your displayed code is invalid because you have closed the `StackPanel` twice.

Comment: @Sheridan thanks for pointing..changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/pin.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Text="text on image" Name="locationID" />
</Grid>
```

whole idea is to place the image as background of grid and place the text as content of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If what you wanna do is display the index of each item of your datasource in your view, there are a couple of ways to do this.

- You can save the item's index on a property of the datasource itself and bind that value in your view. This is probably the simplest solution if your collection is static. Cumbersome if dynamic, you would need to manually update the indexes of your collection changes.
- You could expose the collection in the app level (making it global), write a converter and provide the item of the collection to it. Then you could search and return the index of that item in your global datasource.
- You could implement a multibinding with the [Cimbalino Toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit) providing both the item and the datasource and return the index.